# Limesurvey Openshift unwanted reinstallation when git push new file

Tags: git, openshift, limesurvey

The issue is in modifying files on Openshift while using Limesurvey from the below git

```
https://github.com/gshipley/limesurvey-quickstart
```

After the installation is done and i add a new file at my local repo e.g. php/front-end.html, `git push` it and then visit my limesurvey app at openshift, it again takes me to installer page.

Why it is effecting and resetting limesurvey installation each time i `git push`? and how can i resolve it?

Note: i am not modifying any limesurvey file just adding new one.

Below is the git log:

```
>git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   php/front-end.html
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

>git add php/front-end.html

>git commit -m "Test Front End"
[master dd7f21d] Test Front End
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

>git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean

>git push
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 362 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Not stopping cartridge mysql because hot deploy is enabled
remote: Not stopping cartridge php because hot deploy is enabled
remote: Not stopping cartridge phpmyadmin because hot deploy is enabled
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit dd7f21d
remote: Checking .openshift/pear.txt for PEAR dependency..
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is dc93388e
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Not starting cartridge mysql because hot deploy is enabled
remote: Not starting cartridge phpmyadmin because hot deploy is enabled
remote: Not starting cartridge php because hot deploy is enabled
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
To ssh://<long guid>@appname-namespace.rhcloud.com/~/git/appname.g
it/
   91e3033..dd7f21d  HEAD -> master
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically over-writing any configuration files that are generated during the installation process when you do a git push.
I can see two ways to correct this issue:
1.)  copy the files that are created during installation into your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR (~/app-root/data) and then create symlinks to them in your deploy action hook (.openshift/action_hooks/deploy)
2.)  Do the installation on openshift, then ssh to your gear and copy the files that are created back to your local git working directory and add them to your repository using git add && git commit, then those files will be deployed when you do a git push to your gear.